# How to Change the tab bar on selection similar to ios 7 photos App

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I want to change the tab bar when you enable multiple selection to a UICollectionView or any other similar view like in photos App. Check the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is not a tab bar but a UIToolbar. You can add two toolbars in storyboard. On select button press just fade in the second toolbar(with add button).